# Add Tailwind to a Solidus store

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tailwind-css, solidus

I have been trying to **add Tailwind to a Solidus store** with no luck. Adding Tailwind the usual way you would do on any Rails app does not work, as Tailwind components do not display properly. Unfortunately, I haven't found any guide on how to achieve this.

Basically, I would like to apply changes to [Solidus' Starter Frontend](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus_starter_frontend) using Tailwind.
Adding Tailwind's CDN to `storefront.html.erb` seems to work however (with the text being very small).

**Steps**

1. I have followed every steps on the [Getting Started](https://guides.solidus.io/getting-started/installing-solidus) page from Solidus' official documentation, but with `rails new amazing_store --css tailwind --skip-javascript` instead of just `rails new amazing_store --skip-javascript`.
2. Then, when prompted, I chose to install the [solidus_starter_frontend](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus_starter_frontend) storefront.

I have checked [this repository](https://github.com/gsmendoza/solidus_store/tree/rails-7-0-4--solidus-3-2-2--4685-tailwind) (found on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/issues/4685)) and compared it with my own code and I cannot find any difference with mine.

Do you have any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to StackOverflow just in case some people need it.

Thanks to kennyadsl's [answer](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/discussions/4731) to my GH dicussion and this [thread](https://solidusio.slack.com/archives/C0JBKDF35/p1669038458482229) on the [Solidus official Slack channel](http://slack.solidus.io/), here are the steps to follow to have a Solidus store running with Tailwind:

```
rails new amazing_store # avoid the --skip-javascript flag here
cd amazing_store
bundle add 'solidus'
bin/rails generate solidus:install # devise: Y, payment: none, frontend: starter
bundle add tailwindcss-rails
rails tailwindcss:install
```

In `layout/storefront.html.erb`:

```
-    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'solidus_starter_frontend', media: 'screen' %>
+    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "tailwind", "inter-font", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

Please note that by doing so, you will **lose all the design from the Solidus Starter Frontend** when you implement Tailwind. And that's where the fun part begins!

Then, start Rails with:

```
bin/dev
```

You can now add Tailwind classes to your HTML as you would normally do!